# disable IIS logging for a specific ASP.NET MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, load-balancing

I am having my site load balanced, and for the load balancer I need a route for a heartbeat availability check (/Heartbeat/Verify). I want requests to this route not to be logged by IIS. How can I do that? (I am using IIS 7, ASP.NET MVC 5 and hardware load balancer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, the work-around is to create a directory /Heartbeat/ and disable logging for it in IIS, that way all routes /Heartbeat/* are not logged.